# PySpark DataFrame: Replace Column Values Conditionally

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark Dataframe with two columns:

| id | address_type |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 101 | 1 |
| 102 | 2 |
| 103 | 2 |

I want to change all the values in the `address_type` column.  When `address_type = 1`, it should be `Mailing address` and if `address_type = 2`, it should be `Physical address`.

**Desired Result**

| id | address_type |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Mailing address |
| 101 | Mailing address |
| 102 | Physical address |
| 103 | Physical address |

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: This is very basic. Have you tried something?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz Yes, I figured it out.  `df.withColumn("address_type", when(col("address_type") == 1, "Mailing").otherwise("Physical"))`

Comment: Great! :-) .....

Answer (score 0):

```
df  = spark.createDataFrame(
      [
        ('100','1'),
        ('101','1'),
        ('102','2'),
        ('103','2')
      ], ['id','address_type']
    )

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('address_type', 
              F.when(df.address_type == 1, F.lit('Mailing address'))
               .when(df.address_type == 2, F.lit('Physical address'))
               .otherwise(df.address_type))\
              .show()
```

```
+---+----------------+
| id|    address_type|
+---+----------------+
|100| Mailing address|
|101| Mailing address|
|102|Physical address|
|103|Physical address|
+---+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.replace(['1','2'],['Mailing address','Physical address'],'address_type').show()
```